# Developing JavaME applications on Linux

Tags: java, linux, java-me

I have been tasked to develop a mobile application with java technology. So i went to oracle's website to download the toolkit, then i figured out that Java ME SDK 3.0 is only available on windows and mac.

Now my question is, does it mean that Linux users can't development Java Me applications since the development kit is only available to Windows and Mac users alone?

If a Linux user wants to develop a Java ME application, how would he go about it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last Java ME SDK I successfully used on linux was the Sun Java Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2.   [Found here](http://java.sun.com/products/sjwtoolkit/download-2_5_2.html).  I'm not sure what is holding up 3.0, but if 2.5.2 doesn't pan out, I'd try the Android SDK (Note on the Android SDK: It wouldn't be a Java ME application, but it would be a mobile application using java technology).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much. First of all, what's the difference between a Java ME application and a mobile Java application developed using Andriod SDK? Secondly, will the Java appliation developed with Andriod SDK run on any other Java enabled mobile device apart from an Andriod powered device?

Comment: An application developed using Android will only work on Android OS smartphone or tablet.  A Java ME application should run on any device that is Java ME enabled.

Comment: The whole notion of J2ME (showing my age) was to make a standard across devices that had limited resources like phones.  In today's mobile market a smartphone can do a lot more than a Motorola Razr, so the technology has evolved and frankly outgrown the original intent.  That's why most smartphone development leverages the specific APIs (Android, Blackberry, Iphone, etc).

Comment: But if i go with Andriod, i will still need to develop another version for Blackberry, iPhone and probably Nokia too. But a JavaME app will most likely run on all. If you were in my shoes, whic option will you have gone for?

Comment: Blackberry supports Java ME, but a lot of the technology that makes the Blackberry a Blackberry, require using custom libraries.  Android doesn't support it out of the box, I've seen emulators that can be used to run them on the phone.  As for the porting question you are right. But you may end up dwarfing capability to ensure your app works on all phones (non-smartphone and smartphone alike). It looks like using javascript and html along with other products like Appcelerator to generate the necessary files is the current "silver bullet" solution to the porting question.

Comment: If you were to ask me 4 years ago I would have selected Java ME, for the same reasons you stated.  If you want to work with smartphones and develop on Linux I'd say Android is a good choice.  I'm not knocking Java ME, its still being used in mobile devices.  But the smartphones and tablets market is being created leveraging these native apis and not Java ME.  I'm sure this question has been asked on Stack with ppl more knowledgeable than me responding, I'd also search here and get a second opinion :).

Comment: Thanks so much Beanz. You have been so helpful. I will stick to your advise.

Answer (score 0):

As Beanz said, 2.5.2 is fine. You can download the Eclipse mobile package which has everything. Also check out LWUIT - a fantastic UI toolkit for J2ME (also supported and provided by Oracle/Sun).

Answer (score 0):

Find eclipse pulsar (for mobile developing) and import the library LWUIT. See the manual:
http://jimmod.com/blog/2010/04/basic-lwuit-tutorial-with-eclipse-pulsar/